# Getting the most of the GPU in an Embedded Platform

Tags: optimization, opencv, opengl-es, parallel-processing, embedded

My platform is Ubuntu running ob Exynos4412CPU which has the Mali400GPU. I would like to do some computer vision using OpenCV and OpenGL, I'm also going to do some fragment shaders. My question is what is the fastest way to copy the contents from the GPU to the CPU, which is really slow on my platform using glreadpixels. Is it beneficial to utilize glreadpixels in its own thread or use OpenMP ? Suggestions are welcome please :).

Comment: i'm no expert here, but current  opencv comes with a gpu(i think, that's cuda) as well as a opencl module nowadays. translating any problem into shaders working on top of opengl might not be the best way( eg, you can only work on  pixels there)

Comment: @berak My GPU doesn't support neither cuda nor opencl

Comment: oh, same here ;) ok. understand your motives now, doing it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exynos 4412 doesn't have separate CPU and GPU memory at the hardware level; it's all the same RAM and physically accessible by both.  Thus, there is likely to be some way to access the GPU's portion of the memory directly from the CPU.

Comment: Exynos 4412 is base on Cortex A9 processor, which has a MMU (memory management unit). It is very likely that the video memory is isolated and cannot be read by a Ubuntu app.